# Need data from a many:many join in a Rails view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, has-and-belongs-to-many

Its maybe not the best solution in most cases, but i want a table with data form 3 tables.

```
class Media < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :type
  has_many :ratings                                           
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :medias
  has_many :ratings
end

class Rating < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :media
end
```

Thats the view I want

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Comment</th>
    <th>Creator</th>
    <th>Type</th>
    <% for user in @users %>
      <th><%=h user.login %></th>
    <% end %>
  </tr>

<% for media in @medias %>
  <tr>
    <td><%=h media.name %></td>
    <td><%=h media.comment %></td>
    <td><%=h media.user.login %></td>
    <td><%=h media.type.name %></td>
    <% for user in @users %>
      <td><%=h GET_RATING (media, user) %></td>
    <% end %>%>
  </tr>
<% end %>
</table>
```

Basicly i want one new row for each users ratings for each media

What I want is a Table that looks like that:

```
media.name  media.comment ...   rating(media, user).rating
```

I think it would be better to use a join in the Controller with the Media find methods but I dont know how exactly, enougher possible solution could be helper method that takes media and user as parameters.

What do you think is the best solution for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This kind of association belongs in your model, a has many through relationship is perfect for this.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :ratings
  has_many :media, :through => :ratings
end

class Media < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :ratings
  has_many :users, :through => ratings
end

class Rating < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :media
end
```

Then you can access

```
media.name media.comment
```

Then could also access

```
user.ratings
```

or:

```
<% media.users.each do |user| %>
  ## Do stuff with user.ratings array
<% end %>
```

You can also:

```
media.ratings.each do |rating|
  rating.your_attribute
  rating.user.your_attribute
end
```

Comment: thanx that helped a lot, but I get it not running complete:

    <% media.users.each do |rater| %>
      <% rater.ratings.each do |rating| %>
        <td><%=h rating.rating %></td>
      <% end %>
    <% end %>

that is what i have at the moment, the problem is when a user have not given a rating he is not in the list media.users so i get a table with different td count per line.

Comment: no it does not work.

with media.users I get all users who have have give a rating for that movie. with media.users.ratings I get all ratings wich the user gave but not just for that media. So if i give a rating As user A for movie 1 and another rating for movie 2 and then I get for movie 1 both votings and also for the movie 2 both votings.

So the solution is invalid or only partial.

Comment: This the right technique. You need to populate the association.

Comment: K I marked it as answerd because I think you did. At the moment I use another code for the problem "custom fields" where the user can set an heading and a value so that code isnt in the app anymore. But I learned much from it. Thanx